# Скос элемента на css

Tags: css, css3

Можно ли реализовать подобный скос средствами css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так, чтобы содержимое элемента обрезалось по этой границе. Если можно, то как? `transform: skew` не подходит, так как скашивает обе стороны блока.

Comment: Фигура должа получиться цельной?

Comment: @Cheg, должен в итоге получиться блок со скошенной верхней или нижней границей. Идея в том, что внутри этого блока есть фоновое изображение, которое таким образом будет обрезаться. Можно сделать это, накладывая скошенную границу в виде png-изображения, но это лишние обращения к серверу, вот и пришла мысль: возможно, этого можно достичь и другими путями.

Comment: Фоновое изображение устанавливается в "родном" разрешении или как-то масштабирается? Например, через cover или contain?

Comment: @Cheg, `background-size: 100%`, и далее масштабируется в зависимости от размера блока.

Comment: варианты с svg не рассматриваете?

Comment: @Cheg, рассматриваю, если они кроссбраузерные. Насколько я знаю, svg-маски не поддерживаются многими браузерами. И еще внутри блока должно быть содержимое.

Comment: И последний вопрос - текст в этом блоке есть? или только фоновая картинка?

Comment: @Cheg, да, это стандартный блок с содержимым и фоном. В этом и сложность,

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью `shape`, но поддерживается только вебкитовыми браузерами, можно подключить [полифилл](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill)

```css
.shape {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgrey;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.shape:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 20%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">Так, чтобы содержимое элемента обрезалось по этой границе. Если можно, то как? transform: skew не подходит, так как скашивает обе стороны блока.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создавать любые фигуры с помощью clip-path.
Вот ссылка на статью с объяснениями как пользоваться https://webref.ru/layout/shapes-polygon/examples

Answer (score 0):

Цвет в градиенте должен совпадать с цветом подложки.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.block {
  color: white;
  background-color: seagreen;
  position: relative;
  /*для нормальных браузеров*/
  clip-path: polygon(0% 20px, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/*для IE10+*/
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  .block::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightgray 0px, lightgray 50%, transparent 50%, transparent) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et temporibus explicabo eum aliquam voluptates dolore magnam, reiciendis perferendis, neque non quidem laboriosam minima blanditiis corporis fugiat porro asperiores voluptatum nesciunt aspernatur numquam ea. Delectus doloribus quis vel quaerat iste, molestiae veritatis. Quos quaerat illo facere labore dolore minima magnam, enim ipsam cumque nobis repudiandae quia commodi corporis? Nobis fuga architecto saepe impedit tempore minus modi quia esse officia quos commodi aliquid nulla necessitatibus, sunt placeat molestias blanditiis nostrum! Exercitationem similique, architecto ipsa repellendus sed sunt impedit inventore molestiae porro at numquam obcaecati aut atque, incidunt eos enim ipsam nesciunt quasi.
</div>
```